# read output of txt file has white spaces

Tags: java, windows, cmd

i got the list of applications from cmd command using /output:D:\list.txt product get name,version. However when i try to retrieve the list using java the output has white spaces after each letter.

**SAMPLE:**

*from text file*

```
links

images

lists
```

*when read in java*

```
 l i n k s

 i m a g e s 

 l i s t s
```

is there a way to fix this problem?

i just used this code:

```
public void myreader() throws IOException {
 Path path = Paths.get("D:\\list.txt");
 Charset charset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");
 try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path,charset)) {
      String line = null;
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
           System.out.println(line);
      }
 }
```

Comment: Please paste the code you used to read line from the file.

Comment: I ran the code your posted and the results I had did not have the spaces between each character.

Comment: I had the same results as @Mick : ran the code, didn't see spaces.

Comment: the txt file was generated from a cmd command. when i ran it with other text files there are no spaces between characters. but with the txt file from the cmd output, i can see the spaces

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be due to the encoding problem. Try using `UTF-16` character set

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(path), "UTF-16"));
```

Answer (score 0):

### Have you tried the FileReader?

```
FileReader fileReader;
try {
    fileReader = new FileReader( "D:\\list.txt" );
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( fileReader ); 
    String line; 
    while( ( line = bufferedReader.readLine() ) != null )
    { 
        System.out.println( line ); 
    }
    fileReader.close();
} catch ( IOException except ) {
    System.err.println( except.getStackTrace()[0] );
}
```

Im not shure where your problem is coming from, but you may take the FileReader for such instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you read a UTF-16 encoded file.

Give a hint to your Reader - pass "UTF-16", instead of "ISO-8859-1".