# Java read text file extrange line

Tags: java, system.out

I am trying to process a csv file in java, but when print the result, the text have too many spaces.

[image]

With this code print like the img above:

```
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("prueba.csv");
// or using Scaner
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
String strLine;
//Read File Line By Line
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
  System.out.println(strLine);
}
```

}

If open the file in for example notapad++ or windows notepad it looks well. I tried to remove spaces but it too was not success :(
What can I do?

Comment: Do you have an example of your code?

Comment: What charset is your JVM writing in; what charset is notepad(++) reading it in?

Comment: Why are you wrapping `fstream` in a `DataInputStream`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you as per the https://stackoverflow.com/a/14411707/4848659.
Change bufferedReader initialization as follows,

`BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream, "UTF16"));`

Comment: Thanks, it work!! :)